# Платное облачное хранилище для создания кинотеатра?

Tags: dropbox, облачное-хранилище, onedrive

Какие существуют хранилища с открытым доступом для каждого пользователя с, желательно, безлимитным трафиком. Идея - бэкенд и фронтенд лежит на VPS. Фильмы в облаке. Нужно брать их из облака и быстро и контролируемо поставлять пользователю.

Можно ли для этих целей использовать платные тарифные планы DropBox'a, Google Disk'a, OneDrive?